# Sharepoint installation in windows7

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is it possible to install MOSS 2007 in Windows 7. If possible, What are the requirements? Please help me

Answer (score 3):

Possible with a ton of hacking and general messing around.

Licensed and supported? Naw.

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2008/05/21/how-to-install-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0-sp1-on-vista-x64-x86.aspx